# Dom element not found in lazy loaded angular component

Tags: angular, typescript, lazy-loading, nebular

I have a nebular stepper component and for the final step, I lazy load the component. In that component, I need to identify an element by id and make changes to it.

Stepper component where lazy loading takes place:

Html-

```
 <nb-step [label]="labelFour">
          <ng-template #labelFour>Fourth step</ng-template>
          <h3>Edit Your Image</h3>
          
          <div class="container step-container">
              <ng-template #canvasContainer ></ng-template>
              
            
          </div>


          <button nbButton nbStepperPrevious>prev</button>
          <button nbButton nbStepperNext>next</button>
</nb-step>
```

TS-

```
  @ViewChild('canvasContainer', {read: ViewContainerRef}) canvasContainer: ViewContainerRef;
  canvasInitialized = false;

  async createCanvas() {
    await this.lazyLoadCanvas();
    this.canvasInitialized = true;
    
  }
  private async lazyLoadCanvas() {
    const {CanvasComponent} = await import('../../single/canvas/canvas.component');

    const canvasFactory = this.cfr.resolveComponentFactory(CanvasComponent);
    const {instance} = this.canvasContainer.createComponent(canvasFactory, null, this.injector);
    

  }
  noDesignSelected:boolean;
  thirdStepNext(){           //Third step is clicked
   
    if(this.postDesignService.designID != -1){
      this.stepper.next();
      this.noDesignSelected = false;
      this.createCanvas();
    } else {
      this.noDesignSelected = true;
    }
    
  }
```

Component that's loaded in-

Html-

```
<div class="canvas-bg">
    <div id="container" ></div>
</div>
```

TS-

```
ngAfterViewChecked() {
    document.getElementById('container').classList.add('test');   //error here

    this.stage = new Konva.Stage({
      container: 'container',            //error here
      width: this.stageWidth,
      height: this.stageHeight,
    });
}
```

The error tells me that an element with id 'container' can't be found.

I've tried ngOninit, ngAfterViewInit, and ngAfterViewChecked (as seen above). I've tried assigning the element to a Viewchild and changing the style of that viewchild.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a **Viewchild** using **#ref** instead of an id

Something like

```
<div class="canvas-bg">
    <div *#ref* id="container" ></div>
</div>
```

In your ts file:

```
@ViewChild("ref") ref;
```

And, then call inside
**ngAfterViewInit**
like `this.ref.nativeElement.textContent`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately I get the same error. I believe it's something weird with how nebular handles its stepper content that's causing the afterviewchecked to run before the container is there.